# Does Firebreath 1.6 support Internet Explorer 10?

Tags: plugins, activex, internet-explorer-10, firebreath

Does anybody know if there are some basic problems using a firebreath-built plugin on IE10?

A plugin that I built using FB 1.6 that works fine on IE9 on Windows 7, no longer works on IE10 on Windows 8 classic desktop.  I suspect some issue with the ActiveX interface.  I installed Chrome on Win8 classic and the plugin works OK on that browser.

Admittedly, I don't have many debugging details yet.  But I wanted to see if there were any general issues I should be aware of before diving through the FB code.

Thanks very much.

Bob

Comment: My 1.6 plugin works like charm also in IE10.

Comment: btw, you should really update to firebreath 1.7; there are no breaking changes, but lots of bug fixes

Answer (score 1):

There are no fundamental incompatibilities that I'm aware of, however our plugin does seem to have some drawing issues in IE10 that I haven't had the luxury of tracking down yet.

If you could be more specific about what "no longer works" means it might be easier to give you some advice.

Does it fail to load? Fail to talk to javascript? Fail to draw (like ours)? Crash the browser? Curdle your milk and demagnetize your credit cards? Sing Beatles songs out of tune?

Without some indication of what exactly is going wrong it's hard to know what to tell you.